# Do comments belong in the "Syntax" list?

Tags: discussion, documentation

People are sometimes putting comments in the syntax list:

[image]

**Is this a good thing?**

- Should the *list* (be allowed to) be a *table* with `sytax | explanation` instead?

**Or does it just add noise?**

- Shouldn't the *explanation* come from examples and remarks?

Comment: Only put them when it's *really* necessary. For example you can't use version wrappers in the syntax section. cf http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/inline-version-is-not-compatible-with-the-syntax-section?noredirect=1

Answer (score 7):

I've been rooting around that specific page on Docs, and I've been trying to consider if that would look *better* or *worse* without the comments.  My gut tells me it'd look worse, so I would prefer to keep those specific comments in there.

That said, it does muddle the scope of that field a bit.  If it's intended *just* to be a place to house syntax, that doesn't help all that much, since I don't know why those parameters are there or what purpose they serve.  If it's intended to do a bit more explanation, then I agree that we should be able to add a simple (~200 characters) blurb of what the syntax of this specific thing is, and why it's this way.

Comment: Then do it so if you click on the syntax it folds out a textbox underneath it with additional information?